# Issue on Positioning .span inside a .row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having lots of problems on positioning three column inside a `.row` using `.span` Can you please take a look at [THIS LINK](http://promap.ca/Agent.html) and let me know what I am doing wrong! on here?
if you check the page in iPhone 5 landscape orientation you will see that all there spans will line up under each other but I would like to keep two first at the first line. Here is what happening:

[image]

and this is what I would like to have:

[image]

also in big screens the third span is not fitting at the right end part:

[image]

or in iPhone 5 portrait view I woud like to center the image but it looks like:

[image]

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Comment: you should post your relevant markup here or in a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap makes all `spanX` elements display as block in small screens, so you can try adding a new class to make your spans float on small screens too, also I suggest you use the `.row-fluid` class and float your `.social-wrap` to make it align to the right

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 floatSmall">
        <img />
    </div>
    <div class="span4 floatSmall">
        <!--YOUR .span4 CONTENT-->
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="footer-body">
            <div class="social-wrap">
                <ul id="social-networking">
                    <!--YOUR SOCIAL LINKS-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.social-wrap {
    float: right;
    /*remove the width you have set*/
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
    .floatSmall {
        width: auto!important;
        float: left!important;
    }
}
```